# Как сделать с помощью ajax'a обновление контента для всех пользователей?

Tags: javascript, ajax

К примеру один пользователь делает ставку, т.е. сумма ставки изменяется после перезагрузки страницы. С помощь ajax сделал так, чтоб сумма изменялась без перезагрузки страницы. Но она меняется лишь у одного пользователя, а остальные должны перезагрузить страницу. А как сделать, чтоб контент менялся у всех пользователей?

Comment: Если интересует решение именно с помощью ajax'а, то можете по таймеру отправлять ajax запросы от каждого пользователя. Однако я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону сокетов.

Comment: Отправь ставку пользователя  в базу данных и потом обновляй для всех беря эти данные